# Grunt with selenium grid

Tags: gruntjs, protractor, selenium-grid2

Could anybody make grunt work with selenium grid? I could set up grid by passing the role: hub under serverOptions of start-selenium-server task in my gruntfile but soon end up getting -

Error: Timeout waiting for selenium to start.  Check if an instance of selenium is already running.
Warning: Task "start-selenium-server:config" failed. Use --force to continue.

I am using grunt with protractor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by of making grunt work with protractor. In the config file followed the pattern as per the solution provided here -

[protractor remote tests multibrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564777/protractor-remote-tests-multibrowser)

While from my grunt file removed the capabilities section. Though i would have loved to not hard code the browser name, as of now could find this as the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, i was trying to explicitely start a hub and then register a node. Using seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' in the config file sets up the hub and registers the nodes on using multi capabilities.